# How can I add a new line to a text document

Tags: c#, text

I was wondering, how can i add a new line to a text document. For an instance, I have a text document with numbers or whatever which contains the following two lines of text:

"444444

323233"

And I want to add a new line, in which would like to add new combination of numbers, so how can I do that? I first save all lines in a array, print them and ask the user to choose which line to edit and if the chosen line does not exist (in this situation if the user types the number "3" in the variable n), I want the program to create a new line.

```
string path = C:\...\text1.text
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
int i = 1;

foreach (var line in lines)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1}", i, line);
     i++;
}

Console.Write("Choose which line to edit: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
n--;

Console.Write("{0}. ", n + 1);
lines[n] = lines[n].Replace(lines[n], Console.ReadLine());

File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following line of code with mention code:

```
 string path = C:\...\text1.text
 List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
 int i = 1;

 foreach (var line in lines)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1}", i, line);
   i++;
 }

  Console.Write("Choose which line to edit: ");
  int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  n--;

 Console.Write("{0}. ", n + 1);

lines.Insert(n, Console.ReadLine());

File.WriteAllLines(path, lines.ToArray());
```

Comment: I don't think it will work, because we are replacing the Nth item of the array which does not exist. Therefore - exception.

Comment: Yes, array out of range exception. We can't tell it to edit a line which does not exist

Comment: @Sapphire check now I edited my answer, This will add new line as user wanted index position check syntax also!

Comment: there is no "insert" method

Comment: @Sapphire did u change string[] into list,second line from top? Replace complete ur code with suggested code. Since array dont have insert extention.

Comment: Yeah,yeah. And how can i edit that new line later? I want the user to type its value.

Comment: @Sapphire I think u want to add user line at required index, not new line. Simply replace Environment.NewLine with Console.ReadLine and u shall get required result. Check edited answer

Comment: oh my god, yeah. I blocked entirely. Thank you Ankush, really appreciate it

Comment: Can you tell me whats the difference between .Add and .Insert?

Comment: @Sapphire .Add will add element at the end of collection and .Insert will add element at required index.

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.NewLine` Property Gets the newline string defined for this environment.

```
// Sample for the Environment.NewLine property 
 using System;

  class Sample 
   {
      public static void Main() 
      {
         Console.WriteLine();
         Console.WriteLine("NewLine: {0}  first line{0}  second line{0}  third line",
                      Environment.NewLine);
      }
   }
   /*
        This example produces the following results:

         NewLine:
         first line
         second line
         third line
    */
```

Comment: Yeah, but i want the user to choose how to edit that exact new line and i want that line to be added to the text document.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here:

[AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For all File Methods:

[File Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The AppendAllText has a signature:

```
public static void AppendAllText(
    string path,
    string contents
)
```

to use:

```
File.AppendAllText("path/to/file/that/exists/myfile.txt", "Your new line here");
```